# Creación automática de usuario a partir de email

Tags: mercadopago

¿Es posible la creación de usuarios en base a un email solamente?
De ser así, ¿con qué credenciales se crea para loguearse y recibir los pagos?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para que se ajuste a las políticas del sitio. Usa esta guía _[ask]_. De ser posible agrega un __[mcve]__. Es probable que te interese leer esta pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que te refieres a crear usuarios (https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/customers-and-cards/), en ese caso los parámetros mínimos para crear un usuario vía api efectivamente solo es el mail.

El snippet en PHP seria algo como:

```
<?php

  require_once ('mercadopago.php');

  $mp = new MP ("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN");

  $customer = $mp->post ("/v1/customers", array("email" => "test@test.com"));

  print_r ($customer);

?>
```

El concepto usuario, permite registrar en MercadoPago una referencia a un usuario de tu aplicación, esto con el fin de guardar sus tarjetas para futuros pagos.

Si te refieres a crear usuarios de MercadoPago de forma dinámica, esto por lo pronto no es posible mas que para los usuarios de prueba (https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/related/test-users/).

> Si te refieres a un usuario estándar de MercadoPago con registro
>   manual, no, se necesitan mas datos, algunos medios de pago requieren
>   mas información que otros por lo que mientras mas datos es mejor, de
>   otro modo podrías no tener todos los medios de pago disponibles en
>   algunos casos. (Las credenciales las puedes obtener en: https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/account/credentials?type=basic)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!
Con respecto a este tema, si hago el POST con un email que no pertenezca a un usuario de MercadoPago, obtengo del servidor igualmente una respuesta válida.
Ahora, si yo hiciera pagos al ID que me devuelve, cómo haría el dueño de este email para poder cobrar los pagos.

Comment: A cual de los casos de refieres, menciono 3

Comment: Al primero, que es el que cumpliría con lo que necesito.

Comment: Repasemos ese concepto, en el primer escenario permite registrar en MercadoPago un usuario de tu aplicación (No quiere decir que crea un usuario de MercadoPago) y esto es para poder guardar tarjetas asociadas a un usuario y realizar pagos, por ejemplo serviría para escenarios donde: Tienes un propia tienda y tu gestión de usuarios independiente, pero quieres que cada usuario pueda guardar las tarjetas que usa para pagar, entonces cuando algún usuario se registre en tu tienda, también registras un customer de mercado pago y puede luego pedir al api por las tarjetas guardadas de ese usuario.